# Get the selected value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I am attempting to pull information from my `listview` but cannot seem to select a specific `dataset`. When pulling information from this I always get the entire contents back but can never read just one set.

I will be pulling the row data as:

```
chartViewList2.SelectedItem
```

I added information to the list view via

```
  private void getServices(string ComputerName)
    {
        chartListView2.Items.Clear();
        ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices(ComputerName);

        foreach (ServiceController service in services)
        {
            chartListView2.Items.Add(new { Service = service.ServiceName, Status =     service.Status, Desc = service.DisplayName });
        }
    }
```

List View XML:

```
    ListView x:Name="chartListView2" Margin="12,59,46,6"
              GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler2">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Service" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Service}" Width="100"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" Width="60"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Desc" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Desc}" Width="190"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

All I want to get from this is the Service name field back.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection may help here.

```
var item = chartViewList2.SelectedItem;
var type = item.GetType();
var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("Service");
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null);
```

Then you will have a value of Service field in 'value' variable.

Since .NET 4 and dynamic keyword even shorter way exists:

```
dynamic item = chartViewList2.SelectedItem;
dynamic propertyValue = item.Service;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding your `ListView` to a `List<TypedObject>` then you can do this:

```
var item = chartViewList2.SelectedItem as TypedObject
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `ListView` `SelectedvaluePath` to `Service` and bind to your model or access using the `ListView` `SelectedValue`.

Example:

```
   <ListView x:Name="chartListView2" SelectedValuePath="Service" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedServiceName}" >
```